# Different Assembly loading results between MS.NET and Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-assembly

We are currently developing an application in C# that is targeted to .NetFramework,Version=4.6. We are compiling the application in Visual Studio on Windows, but deploying it in a docker container running Mono:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.2 (Stable 4.4.2.11/f72fe45 Fri Jul 29 09:58:49 UTC 2016)
```

In this application we dynamically generate code using the Roslyn compiler and then load the result into an Assembly (without setting the Assembly metadata).

When we run this application on Windows, all works correctly. We generate the code, compile it and load the assembly. We can change the code, re-compile the assembly and load it back. On Windows, this all works and the loaded types are all updated successfully.

However, moving onto Mono, we see that the first compile of the Assembly is successfully loaded as expected, but subsequent changes to the compiled Assembly are not loaded and the initial loaded Assembly is always returned.

i.e.

On Windows we compile code A with `class A1`. Load the assembly:

```
var a = Assembly.Load(byte[]));
```

and we then get our type from the assembly:

```
var t = a.GetType("A1");
```

Then change the code `class A1; class B1`, recompile, reload and we can get `B1`

On Mono, we can get type `A1`, but when we want to change to `B1` the type is not there and it always keep the first compiled Assembly as a return.

Is there any way of getting Mono to produce the same results as Windows?

Comment: You should be using a different app domain and using DoCallback, unload and reload the app domain.

Comment: seems you found the exact place where Mono is behaving different than MS.NET, so it should be really easy for you to submit a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ attaching a self-contained minimal testcase to reproduce the difference, so that the Mono developers can reproduce it on their own